# Print on Closed File handle : Use Warnings- Perl

Tags: perl, warnings

I am trying to open a file handle, print the filehandle and close it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open( $fh, ">>", "$filename");
print $fh $mesg."\n";
close $fh;
```

Now when I try to compile this file it throws error: `print() on closed filehandle $fh`

This issue has come up only after I have added use warnings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *This issue has come up only after I have added use warnings* - well, no, the problem has always been there but you've only just become aware of it :-)

Comment: what I meant by issue is the compilation error, It also did run correctly with expected output, now I am stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

You should *always* check the return value of [open](http://p3rl.org/functions/open):

```
open my $fh, '>>', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
```

Alternatively, you can use [autodie](http://p3rl.org/autodie) so that `open` will fail even if you don't check its return value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this, it throws, "Can't open <location>"

Comment: Nothing else? No colon? Also, is there a file named `<location>`?

Comment: Yes it says  <location> : 21

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I am connecting to a Linux server, using ssh

Comment: Are you sure you included `$!` inside the double quotes? It shouldn't return a number in string context.

Comment: yes I have added $! inside the double quotes. 
the $filename variable is coming as parameter to the sub and will hence have dynamic value.

Comment: the filename that is being displayed is my work location, 
Is use warnings trying to check whether file open will work and since the $filename variable is not defined, takes instead my base work location and causing failure

Comment: @fthomas: It's very strange that you're getting 21 rather than a descriptive string. But the error number 21 means that you're trying to carry out a file operation on a directory. Does `$filename` contain a filename or a directory name?